# How to implement View Model for DatagGrid with rows calculated based on other rows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

I'm working on a financial application which is based on WPF DataGrid Control and MVVM design pattern. In this application, I need DataGrid to show rows which are calculated based on other rows. In following figure Unite Price, Quantity, Service Charges and Tax are data rows. User can edit values of those rows as usual with in-place editing. But other rows (Calculation Rows) are read only and calculated on the fly based on values of data rows and custom expressions given. As an example custom expression for 'Total' will be something like [Unite Price] * [Quantity]. User will be able to add new calculation rows with their own custom expressions.

[image: Sample of DataGrid]

I have a somewhat clear idea about expression engine. But I'm thinking how View Model should be implemented in this scenario. Specially, view model should be smart enough to update calculated values without refreshing whole DataGrid when the user changes some precedent value in a data row. Currently I have put data rows and calculation rows in the same Observable Collection. But the real problem is how view model facilitates the communication between data rows and calculation rows when necessary, to keep calculated values up to date.

Any good suggestions, advice on this problem or link to a source code of similar implementation will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create base class or interface for your records and implement two versions of it: data holder and data summary. 
Model is a simple class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. ModelSummary derives from Model and have computed properties. Also it have to listen to Models PropertyChange event. I'm overriding virtual properties for simplicity:

```
public class ModelSummary : Model
{
    private IEnumerable<Model> models;
    public ModelSummary(IEnumerable<Model> models)
    {
        this.models = models;
        foreach (Model model in models)
        {
            model.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
        }
    }

    public override int Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return models.Sum(m => m.Value1);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in ViewModel:

```
var list = new List<Model>
{
    new Model {Value1 = 1, Description = "A"},
    new Model {Value1 = 1, Description = "B"}
};

Values = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list)
{
     new ModelSummary(list) { Description = "Summary" }
};
```

I haven't took into account possibility to add a new records.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. yes how to add new records is a problem.

Comment: Your questions doesn't say about new records. You can change `list` to observable collection and update `ModelSummary` based on `CollectionChanged` event `models.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("Value1");`